# Как запустить не-Main.java файл на Repl.it?

Tags: java, ооп

Уважаемые, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно выйти из ситуации? Постигаю азы ООП, и пишу код на работе на сайте repl.it. Создаю новый Repl, удаляю базовый файл Main.java, создаю простецкий класс с объектом в файле Cat.java:

```
public class Cat {
  String name;
  int age;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cat Mars = new Cat();
    Cat.name = "Mars";
    Cat.age = 1;
    System.out.println(Cat.name + " & " + Cat.age);
  }
}
```

Жму на Run, и выдаёт ошибку: "unable to run, main file "Main.java" not found". Т. е. Repl'у важно, чтобы в обязательном порядке в проекте присутствовал файл Main.java, а уже потом всё остальное. Как выкрутится? Мне не нужен этот Main.java. Я пока хочу создавать/прописывать котов с хорьками, и только.
Можно типа некий трюк провернуть, но я не понял как. :( [Там](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174031/how-to-run-java-class-file-from-another-class-file-java-newb) в ответах одна строчка кода, вырванная из контекста.
В общем, на конкретном примере моего небольшого кода как быть, что бы я мог создавать классы, объекты, называя их так, как мне хочется, и чтобы меня не волновало существование файла Main.java в проекте. Ну пусть он практически или вовсе пустой висит и всё, если уж без него совсем никак. Но только как в моём коде этот трюк провернуть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить вложенный класс с котиком:

```
class Main {
  private static class Cat {
    private String name;

    public Cat(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public void meow() {
      System.out.println("Cat " + this.name + " says \"MEOW!!1\"");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cat cat = new Cat("Yasa");
    cat.meow();
  }
}
```

Либо создать отдельный класс `Cat.java`

```
public class Cat {
  private String name;

  public Cat(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void meow() {
    System.out.println("Cat " + this.name + " says \"MEOW!!1\"");
  }
}
```

и вызвать его в Main.java

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cat cat = new Cat("Yasa");
    cat.meow();
  }
}
```